# How do you properly terminate a Service, stopService() not working?

Tags: android, service, background-process

Unable to terminate a Service created in Android, it remains running after stopService. Starting the services as follows:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(i);
```

Associated Manifest entry:

```
 <service android:name=".services.MyService" ></service>
```

The gist of MyService that will persist across several activities, so I did not use a IntentService:

```
package com.sample.app.services;

public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
private Handler handler;

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MyService Intent...  Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    handler = new Handler();

            myProcessing();

    //  This will cause the service to hang around
    return (START_STICKY);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return (null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

In various activities and even attempted it in onDestroy() above, prior to super.onDestroy(); above I tried the following:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    stopService(i);
```

MyService just continues to run. I believe by definition the service is a Singleton.

Comment: I think you must implement onDestroy and stop all worker thread within this event!

Comment: Tried onDestroy() first, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stop the serivce there are two ways you can do it,

1) Call stopself() within in the service class.

2) Using stopService().

IN your case , Saying that your service class is in a diferrent package (even if it's in the same package thats fine) it's better you use aa intent filter for your service, which makes it easy to stop and start a service like the below.

```
<service android:name=".services.MyService" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/myService" >
            <action   android:name="custom.MY_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and add this in your service class

```
public static final String ServiceIntent = "custom.MY_SERVICE"
```

and then you can start or stop the service like the below.

```
startService(new Intent(MyService.ServiceIntent));
stopService(new Intent((MyService.ServiceIntent));
```

Hope this is helpfull. Thankyou

Comment: stopSelf() didn't work, but I will see how the intent filter works. Tks.

Comment: Can you post your log

Comment: @Jois "Service Intent must be explicit", getting this exception, can you give me solution?